# Convert a single Scss file to CSS using compass-watch

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, sass, compass

I am tired to convert Scss modules to CSS one by one manually. I just want to convert my individual Scss file from many modules. I am using compass watch on command line based compiling CSS through **ruby on rails** service for **compass**.

Here you can see how I am managing Scss to CSS conversion through **ror cli**.[image: cli compass watch]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a scss or sass file where you will import all partials.

Example: create a sass file inside your sass directory and name it as you want, maybe `app.sass`.

Inside `app.sass`, import all you partials like so: `@import 'partials/button-actions'`

Create `config.rb` in the directory where you starting watcher. I prefer to use the project root directory.

Inside `config.rb` insert:

```
require 'compass/import-once/activate'
# Require any additional compass plugins here.

# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
# Change paths to yours. css_dir is css output directory, sass_dir is your sass file directory
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "css"
sass_dir = "sass"
images_dir = "i"
javascripts_dir = "js"

# You can select your preferred output style here (can be overridden via the command line):
# output_style = :expanded or :nested or :compact or :compressed
output_style = :compressed

# To enable relative paths to assets via compass helper functions. Uncomment:
# relative_assets = true

# To disable debugging comments that display the original location of your selectors. Uncomment:
# line_comments = false


# If you prefer the indented syntax, you might want to regenerate this
# project again passing --syntax sass, or you can uncomment this:
preferred_syntax = :sass
# and then run:
# sass-convert -R --from scss --to sass sass scss && rm -rf sass && mv scss sass
```

And start watcher. You will get an `app.css` file which contains all the code from the imported files as the result. Import it into your HTML.

Comment: am using this method already. am saying i don't want to convert whole project i just want to convert any single file from project

Comment: @Muzamil301 rename you partial file from `_button-action.scss` to `button-action.scss`

Comment: thanks bro its working but ignoring all variables :-)

Comment: @Muzamil301 variables needed only in developement, so you can import them into every file you need. But variables file should be like `_vars.scss` because it shouldn't be compiled into css. (CSS3 doesn't supports variables)